# Installing Kivy on Banana Pi running Armbian 23.08.0-trunk bookworm

Tags: python, kivy, banana-pi, armbian

After getting Armbian running on my bananapi I tried installing kivy by following the directions on their website and running `python -m pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples`
and `pip3 install kivy[base] --no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir`
but to no avail. Every time I run it, it gets stuck at building wheels for kivy and ends with  this:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Any help would be appreciated